# Countdown Timer - When it reaches 0 change to highlight it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, timer-jobs, flow, power-automate

When I use the countdown timer (app) it gets to 0 and then counts up, there is no visual clue that its now late.

I cannot add JavaScript, and can only use certain apps. Is there a setting I can get to, or ask to be turned on?

Do I need a flow - if so how?  (sorry, very new to SharePoint).

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

There is no stetting available to highlight the Countdown timer web part is SharePoint as this is OOTB webpart.

I am not able to see the **Count direction** option in web part properties (as given in below documentation):

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use the Countdown timer web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-countdown-timer-web-part-a13ffef8-0bf1-409e-be23-98af1d1736e7).

**OOTB workaround**:

If you are able to see the **Count direction** then set it to **Count down** so that it will start counting from event date to current date and it will show 00:00:00:00 as given in below image:

[image]

**Custom solution workaround**:

Or you can create your own countdown timer web part using [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview). This way you will have full control over your webpart and you can highlight after the count is completed.

**Sample webpart**: [SPFxCountdownTimer](https://github.com/CreativeAcer/SPFxCountdownTimer).